Is it possible to have multiple versions of MacOS on the same laptop at the same time?
I am currently running MacOS Sonoma on a Macbook M3. I would also like to have Ventura on the same laptop. Is this possible? If yes, how do I achieve this?

Yes, this is possible so longer as the version you want to install is compatible with your computer. Generally you can't run versions that came out before your computer was released.
The feature you’re looking for is “APFS Volumes:”
In Disk Utility, Select your current startup disk (Macintosh HD) and then click the plus button in the toolbar to add a new volume. This is different from a partition. Leave the default APFS selection and optionally set a quota by clicking "Size Options...". The quota cannot be changed so only select if you’re sure.
Once you have a new volume, download the installer (Apple Support - How to Download macOS) and select your new volume during installation.
To switch between them, use the startup disk option in System Settings

@Gilby The macOS ventura download is for 13.6.7 and certainly supports the initial MacBook Pro. I'll make a note about not running older versions this way.

You are right.  Ignore my comment, I will delete it.

The easy way to do this is run the second OS virtually on top of the first.

https://eclecticlight.co/virtualisation-on-apple-silicon/

Especially if “at the same time” means concurrently. I’d start with VMWare Fusion or Parallels based on your M3 chip and how you like their features, prices and documentation. There are less commercial options as well (see the three different VM apps from Howard Oakley on Eclectic Light above)

https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/

If you need to run the OS sequentially, the easiest is to install the second OS on an external drive. Download the installer and when you run it, choose the second drive for where to install.
Note, firmware and iCloud are items you should plan out before you implement a full setup. Also note, Apple supports virtualization officially, but this is for developers of the tools, and not end user support. They will assist you in dual boot situations but make sure you always have a backup if their support recommends erasing everything and starting with a clean setup if you try to install two MacOS on one drive.

https://eclecticlight.co/2024/06/24/firmware-matters/


VMware Fusion Pro (Player is not longer available). Free or paid depending on intended usage.

Thanks @Gilby let me edit that one word out. They have player listed on the web page, but I think Pro being free is the way to go here at a minimum. It may not allow macOS guest though still…

you can also use UTM which is free

Apple’s article about dual booting.
Use more than one version of macOS on same computer
